# LESS/Grunt is not writing the sourcemap reference to the end of the compiled CSS

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-less

I am using `grunt-contrib-less` to compile my `.less` files in to a single CSS stylesheet. Everything is working, except the source map, which I cannot get to work under any circumstances!

Here is my Gruntfile:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Force use of Unix newlines
grunt.util.linefeed = '\n';

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    project: {
        // Add entries to this array to create variables for use by Grunt
        app:        ['app'],
        server:     'http://mysite.app',

        // Components
        bower:      ['<%= project.app %>/bower_components'],
        bootstrap:  ['<%= project.bower %>/bootstrap'],

        // Custom Assets
        assets:     ['<%= project.app %>/assets'],
        css:        ['<%= project.assets %>/css'],
        less:       ['<%= project.assets %>/less'],
        js:         ['<%= project.assets %>/js']
    },
    less: {
        production: {
            options: {
                ieCompat:           true,
                sourceMap:          true,
                sourceMapFilename:  '<%= project.css %>/style.css.map',
                sourceMapURL:       '<%= project.server %>/assets/css/style.css.map',
                sourceMapBasepath:  'app',
                sourceMapRootpath:  '<%= project.server %>'
            },
            files: {
                '<%= project.css %>/style.css': '<%= project.less %>/style.less'
            }
        }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= project.assets %>/css/style.css': '<%= project.assets %>/css/style.css'
            }
        }
    },
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';\n',
            sourceMap: true
        },
        plugins_head: {
            // Add further Javascript plugins to this array and they will be
            // concatenated in to the plugins-built-head.js file
            src: [
                '<%= project.bower %>/modernizr/modernizr.js'
            ],
            dest: '<%= project.js %>/built/plugins-built-head.js'
        },
        plugins: {
            // Add further Javascript plugins to this array and they will be
            // concatenated in to the plugins-built.js file
            src: [
                '<%= project.bootstrap %>/js/dropdown.js'
            ],
            dest: '<%= project.js %>/built/plugins-built.js'
        },
        custom: {
            // Add further custom-written javascript files to this array and
            // they will be concatenated in to the scripts-built.js file
            src: [
                '<%= project.js %>/scripts.js'
            ],
            dest: '<%= project.js %>/built/scripts-built.js'
        }
    },
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: [
                '<%= project.bootstrap %>/less/*.less',
                '<%= project.less %>/*.less'
            ],
            tasks: [
                'less',
                'autoprefixer'
            ],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        js: {
            files: [
                '<%= project.js %>/scripts.js'
            ],
            tasks: ['concat']
        },
        html: {
            files: [
                '<%= project.app %>/*.html'
            ],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run-grunt');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'watch'
]);

};
```

What's happening is that Grunt is writing a proper and correct `style.css.map` file, **but it's not writing the following line to the end of the compiled `style.css` file:**

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=http://mysite.app/assets/css/style.css.map */
```

That's the one line that's missing. Everything else is getting compiled and written correctly. If I *manually* add that line to the end of the compiled CSS, Chrome picks up on the source map properly, but it's not being written in.

Additionally, trying options like `sourceMapFileInline` seems to make no difference - the file is never written inline.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have found a solution by now. This is for other people with the same issue:

- Make sure the soourcemap will be placed in the same folder as css.
- Set `sourceMapUrl` to only the name of the map file.
- This will add the following line to your .css file: `/*# sourceMappingURL=default.css.map */`

Here are the sourcemap settings in my grunt file:

```
sourceMap: true,
sourceMapFilename: "src/assets/css/default.css.map",
sourceMapURL: "default.css.map"
```